# Location in disk where data is flushed Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a basic kafka 2.13_3.10 cluster with one broker, consumer and producer.

I was testing if the

```
log.flush.interval.messages = 10
```

worked properly. It is supposed to write the kafka messages of the topics after 10 messages, but where are they saved in the disk by default??

And, is there any configuration to specify the directory where you want data to be flushed??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kafka you specify where messages are stored via the [`log.dirs`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_log.dirs) settings. By default, the path is `/tmp/kafka-logs`.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, in that property you specify the temporal directory where kafka-brokers save their logs and the messages during that session. But once that broker fails or is turned off, you loose all the information stored there. In the documentation of the log.flush.interval.messages says "The number of messages accumulated on a log partition before messages are flushed to disk". What I refer in this question is about the location where the messages are flushed to disk after receiving 10 messages (in the case of the previous example)

Comment: Before being flushed to disk, messages are in memory. While in memory, if the machine crashes these messages will be lost. That's why Kafka regularly writes (flush) them to disk so they are stored in a persistent way. Also note that the default path `/tmp/kafka-logs` is unsafe and should not be used for production as `/tmp` is typically cleared when rebooting.